# Android layout - RTL ordering of views

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a horizontal linear layout, with a TextView and a EditText for user name input.
The TextView contains the text "Username" and the EditText gets the input.

When ordering the views in an RTL interface (such as Hebrew) the TextView should the right most view and the EditText should appear the the left of it.

LTR

[Username-label] [Username-input]

RTL

[Username-input][Username-label]

Although RTL compatibility can be achieved by reversing the order of the views is there a way to make the horizontal scroll view stack it's children from the right to the left by itself?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a method myself to help me in this. What this method does it takes a parent layout and then loops on each layout in it. And if it finds 2 controls in them, then it swiths there locaitons.

```
 private void LoopControls(int layout) {
    RelativeLayout sc = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(layout);
    Integer iLL = 0;
    int childcount = sc.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childcount; i++) {
        View v = sc.getChildAt(i);
        Class<? extends View> c = v.getClass();

        if (c == LinearLayout.class) {
            LinearLayout l = ((LinearLayout) v);
            l.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            iLL++;
            if (l.getChildCount() == 2) {
                if (l.getChildAt(0).getClass() == TextView.class
                        && l.getChildAt(1).getClass() == RadioButton.class) {
                    TextView t = (TextView) l.getChildAt(0);
                    RadioButton r = (RadioButton) l.getChildAt(1);
                    r.setText(t.getText());
                    t.setText("");
                }
            } else if (l.getChildCount() > 2) {
                for (int j = 0; j < l.getChildCount(); j += 2) {
                    if (l.getChildAt(j).getClass() == TextView.class
                            && l.getChildAt(j + 1).getClass() == RadioButton.class) {
                        TextView t = (TextView) l.getChildAt(j);
                        RadioButton r = (RadioButton) l.getChildAt(j + 1);
                        r.setText(t.getText());
                        t.setText("");
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (c == TextView.class) {
            TextView t = ((TextView) v);
            t.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    }
}
```